# Data structure to store table data in java

Tags: java

What is the best data structure in Java to store data in table format?
i.e, with column headers and a set of rows.
The data consists of less than 10 rows.
Iam dealing with dynamic data. There ca be any number of columns.

Comment: Map will be better, key as row number and value as object of class and   class will contain all the columns as attribute

Comment: You could use an Array.

Comment: https://github.com/jparams/data-store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating an object with fields matching the columns in the spreadsheet.  Then you can use any Data Structure as needed.  For e.g. You need uniqueness, just implement equals and hashcode and use a Set implementation.  You need sorting?  Just implement Comparable and use a TreeSet or sort using Collections.sort().  You need a key-value pair, just use a Map implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my case, I am dealing with dynamic data. Columns are not constant. There can be data with any number of columns.

Comment: @user387419 In  that case I suggest you create a Generic class with an instance variables of type List<T> and String.  The String will be the column header and the List will contain the values.  We can then create multiple instances of this class to represent columns of your data.  This is a way of columnar data structure as opposed to tuple based.

Answer (score 0):

You would need two-dimensional array, for example:

```
int [ ] [ ] scores = {{ 20, 18, 22, 20, 16 },
                      { 18, 20, 18, 21, 20 },
                      { 16, 18, 16, 20, 24 },
                      { 25, 24, 22, 24, 25 }};
```

Comment: Please explain something about solution other than just giving one example

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array of Linked List where in the Array you will have Column Header and each element of Array A(1) (Column) will point to corresponding Row.It is an interesting structure as it combines a static structure (an Array use to store Column) and a dynamic structure (Linked Lists use to store Rows) to form a useful data structure.

[image: Array of Linked List]

Hope this might help you

Thanks